# I calculated the power loss of a switching regulator and it doesn't match the datasheet. Am I missing something?

Tags: power-electronics, buck, switching-regulator, efficiency, power-dissipation

I'm trying to figure out how On Semi's LM2575D2T-5G is only 77% efficient. It's the fixed 5 V output version of the component.

The [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm2575-d.pdf) gives V<sub>in</sub> = 12 V and I<sub>load</sub> = 1 A. Based on this, power in = 12 W. Later on in the datasheet, there is a formula to calculate maximum power dissipated in the regulator.

I used the maximum value for V<sub>sat</sub> (1.3V) and I<sub>q</sub> (11 mA) and calculated the loss to be 0.674 W. 11.326 W / 12 W = 94.38% efficient.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you factor in switching losses, and inductor copper and core losses?

Comment: 1A @ 5V is 5W out.  Your assumption that 12Vin @ 1A is wrong.  5V/12V = 41.7% duty cycle.

Comment: "What am I missing here?" (RdsOn+DCR)* Iout ^2 are the main losses

Comment: When you see a datasheet talk about "power dissipated in the regulator", they're only talking about power _in the regulator part itself_. There will be losses elsewhere and those contribute to the overall efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

The losses are not just in the Iq of the switching regulator, there are also parasitic losses in the inductor and switch and diode that are not in the Iq figure, these are most likely included in the 77% efficient figure.

These are also hard to calculate, its usually best to simulate if a model is available

Answer (score 1):

Your output power is 5 V*1 A or 5 W.  Power in will be 5 W plus losses.

The datasheet formula gives conduction losses in the regulator itself, stating that switching losses can be ignored with proper choice of a catch diode.

However, the losses are not only due to the regulator, but also the conduction loss in the external diode and the core and copper losses in the inductor.  The switching losses may not be insignificant either, regardless of what the datasheet says.

So measured efficiency of the overall regulator must take all of those losses into account.

Answer (score 1):

[LM2575 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm2575-d.pdf)

[image]

$$P_{out} = 5V \times 1A =  5W$$

$$P_{in} = \frac {5W} {77\%} = 6.49W$$

We have to come up with **1.5W** (typically) in losses.  Possible sources (from datasheet):

> External components such as the catch diode, inductor, input and output capacitors can affect switching regulator system performance.

> The following formula is to calculate the total power dissipated by the LM2575:

$$P_D = (V_{in} \  I_Q) + d \ I_{Load} \ V_{sat}$$

$$P_D = (12V \times 11mA) + \frac {5V} {12V} \times 1A  \times  1.3V = \boldsymbol{0.673W}$$

Using suggested values from datasheet (from OP above).

[Renco 330μH inductor](https://www.rencousa.com/sites/default/files/productfamilies/pdfs/RL-1952.pdf) (one of the inductors recommended) has 0.300Ω DCR and I2R losses at 1A (Average) = **0.3W**.

A 30 V [1N5818 Schottky Barrier 1A Rectifiers](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/1n5817-d.pdf) has a forward voltage at 0.45V.

$$P_D = (1 - d) \ V_f I_{Avg} = \left (1-\frac {5V} {12V} \right ) \times 0.45V \times 1A = \boldsymbol {0.263W} $$

$$ 1.5W - 0.673W - 0.3W - 0.263W = 0.264W$$

That leaves 0.264W for low ESR (Equivalent Series Resistor) capacitors.  They do not recommend actual capacitors.  \$I_{rms}\$ is the ripple current in inductor.

$$P_D = I_{rms}^2 ESR$$

$$I_{rms} > 1.2 \ d \ I_{Load}$$

Rough analysis, but 77% efficiency makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Iload is going to be the load current, so the wattage to the load will be 5 W. The input current will not be the same as the load current, in a linear regulator it will be more, the load current plus the current to run the regulator, but in a switching regulator it should be less than the load current.

That's the whole point of a switching regulator, instead of the full load current being drawn from the input, it draws enough to make up the power to the load taking the efficiency into account, so to get 5 W out with 12 V in at 77% efficiency you would find the total power
$$ \frac{5 W}{0.77} = 6.5 W$$

And the input current would be
$$ \frac{6.5 W}{12 V} =  542 mA$$

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing here?

If the duty cycle was 100% times Vsat = 1.3 V there is at least  1.3 W loss for 5V*1A=5W output. But a higher input voltage and peak inductor current is divided by the duty cycle with conduction now by the external Schottky diode D1 which may have smaller Vsat loss.

**This estimate is 1.3/5= 26% loss or 74% efficiency which changes with Vinput-Voutput in the datasheet.**

This neglects any loss in L, C. But the main losses are not listed which are RdsOn, Rs of D1, DCR of L1 and ESR of Cout.